# Read the Content fully from a Popen file object

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using subprocess to run a script , get the output of the script on a pipe and process on the output .

I experience a weird problem where in sometimes it reads till the end of the script and someother time it does not go till the end.

I suspect this could be a problem with the buffer size .. tried few alternatives but haven't been succesful yet..

```
def main():
    x = subprocess.Popen('./autotest', bufsize = 1, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, cwd = '/home/vijay/run/bin', shell = True)
    with open("out.txt",'wb') as f:
        for line in x.stdout:
            if 'Press \'q\' to quit scheduler' in line:
                print line.strip()
                f.write(line.strip())
                x.stdin.write('q')
                f.write('\n')
                x.stdin.close()
                x.stdout.flush()
                try:
                    x.stdout.read()
                except:
                    print 'Exception Occured !!!'
                    os._exit(1)
            else:
                print line.strip()
                f.write(line.strip())
                f.write('\n')
                x.stdout.flush()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to `flush()` `x.stdout`?

Comment: Have you tried using communicate? Also, it doesn't seem like you even use the stderr PIPE

Comment: @Amber I used flush() just to see if the  content to read is held up with in the buffer. but that does not actually help

Comment: @jdi Yes. I dont use stderr in this code.. may be i will remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep trying to read from stdout until the process terminates not until stdout ends, use poll() to check if the process terminated and if not, try to read again.

Answer (score 2):

From the Subprocess manual:
[ http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html ]

> Warning Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

This sounds like it may be the problem you are experiencing. For example, if stderr filled up, I believe that could cause the process to block, preventing it from producing further output on stdout.